Fail to build boost library from source under window
Most Boost libraries are header-only, but several Boost libraries must be built.
Following the steps from the link
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source

When Bootstrap.bat is run, b2.exe is generated. Following the tutorial, the command b2 --prefix=one_directory install is run, but the lib files are not generated in the install directory. There is only one folder named .b2 there. Five subfolders and one jam file named
build-system.jam appear in the .b2 folder. Five subfolders all contain only jam file. Search over the network for one solution and fail to find one.
OS： Windows 11
Visual studio: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
